# can i convert a base plot in r to a ggplot object?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, radix

I'm somewhat new to R and I love ggplot - that's all I use for plotting, so I don't know all the archaic syntax needed for base plots in R (and I'd rather not have learn it).  I'm running pROC::roc and I would like to plot the output in ggplot (so I can fine tune how it looks).  I can immediately get a plot as follows:

```
size <- 100
response <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=size)
predictor <- rnorm(100)
rocobject <- pROC::roc(response, predictor,smooth=T)
plot(rocobject)
```

To use ggplot instead, I can create a data frame from the output and then use ggplot (this is NOT my question).  What I want to know is if I can somehow 'convert' the plot made in the code above into ggplot automatically so that I can then do what I want in ggplot?  I've searched all over and I can't seem to find the answer to this 'basic' question.  Thanks!!

Comment: In the `methods`, there is no `ggplot`

Comment: More or less the answer is no. `ggplot2` is built on the `grid` graphic system, which is distinct from ggplot2. It is now possible to combine `grid` graphs with base graphs in a "matrix" of graphs using the `gridGraphics` package.

Comment: Paul murrel did some work to convert base to grid...close to what y ou want https://github.com/pmur002/gridgraphics

Comment: Thanks Tyler - this looks helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never? I think the ggplotify package might do what you want. You basically plug in your plot generating code to the `as.ggplot()` function like so:

```
p6 <- as.ggplot(~plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col=color, pch=15))
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplotify/vignettes/ggplotify.html

Answer (score 3):

No, I think unfortunately this is not possible.

Even though this does not answer your real question, building it with ggplot is actually not difficult.

Your original plot:

```
plot(rocobject)
```

[image]

In ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(y=unlist(rocobject[1]), x=unlist(rocobject[2]))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_reverse() + geom_abline(intercept=1, slope=1, linetype="dashed") + xlab("Specificity") + ylab("sensitivity")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ruthger, can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65404432/r-superimpose-stack-plots-on-top-of-each-other-ggplot2-plotly thank you