# Transform legend into ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, transform, legend

I have made a plot which I would like to transform into ggplot. The problem is that I don´t know how the commmand that I have used for creating the legend could be tranformed.

```
plot(tcg ~ tcw, col=l8tc.df$landcover, data=l8tc.df)
legend('bottomleft', legend=levels(l8tc.df$landcover),  
col=sort(unique(l8tc.df$class)), pch=1, bty='n')
```

`tcg` and `tcw` are both numeric and `l8tc.df$landcover` is a factor with seven different levels

[view plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDA0C.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011885/can-i-convert-a-base-plot-in-r-to-a-ggplot-object

Comment: Your question is very broad. Do some reading into ggplot. E.g., the cookbook. P.S. I am not the downvoter

Comment: I get it, however, the first answer was already exactly what I was looking for so from my point of view the question was put quite allright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you include in your code the actual data or a sample of it to help people answer your question. Without such data I can only guess that this will do what you request:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(l8tc.df, aes(x = tcw, y = tcg, colour = landcover)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    legend.justification = c(0, 0), legend.position = c(0, 0)
  )
```

The output should be a scatterplot with the legend inset to the very bottom left corner of the plot region.